# How to send an alert notification if Async Apex execution limit reached 70%of limit

Tags: rest-api, asyncapexjob

I want to send an alert notification when overall organisation Async Apex Execution limit reached 70%of total limit. Say if limit is 2500 and if system already exhausted 1750 of daily Async Apex Limit out of 2500 then an alert should be send to few persons notifying that your organisation limit of Async Apex Executions have reached 70% threshold.

Comment: I don't know what you mean when you say "Async Apex Execution Limit". Could you be more specific? Are you asking about the 24-hour API call limit, or one of the Apex governor limits (like CPU time, DML rows, or SOQL/SOSL Queries)?

Comment: @DerekF:On 2 occasions in the past month we hit our daily limit on asynchronous Apex executions.Salesforce temporarily increased our limit to 425000 bt will be scaled down to 250000 in a week's time.Once we reach the limit a lot of SF funcs will fail & this has impacted both internal staff & external customers.So to prevent this from happening in the future, we need to create some kind of alert in Salesforce to monitor our daily asynchronous apex method executions.Our maximum daily limit is 250000.The alert will need to create a Case & notify couple of users A & B once it reaches 70% threshold

Answer (score 1):

An out of box solution to receive email alerts to monitor apex limit thresholds exists when you edit the user's detail. It only alerts at 50% and not the 70% as you requested.

> Apex Governor Limit Warning Emails
>
> Additionally, you can enable Apex Governor Limit Warning Emails. When
>   an end-user invokes Apex code that surpasses more than 50% of any
>   governor limit, you can specify a user in your organization to receive
>   an email notification of the event with additional details. To enable
>   email warnings:
>
> 1. Log in to Salesforce as an administrator user.
> 2. Click "Your Name" | Setup | Manage Users | Users.
> 3. Click Edit next to the name of the user who should receive the email notifications.
> 4. Select the Send Apex Warning Emails option.
> 5. Click Save.

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Best_Practice:_Use_of_the_Limits_Apex_Methods_to_avoid_Hitting_Governor_Limits

Comment: Interesting info! I think OP wants roiling 24 though, not single transaction governors.

Comment: Thanks @Joeo. Will the steps mentioned you above trigger an email to user if "Async Apex Execution" Limits reached 50% of threshold.Right now we have 250000 daily limit so if 125000 daily limit consumed then Will user receives an alert notifications

Comment: @harjeet please also don't pester anyone else for answers. Using comments to ask people to answer is inappropriate and mildly abusive behavior.